# Writing an `__array_ufunc__` for string dtypes

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm implementing a class that mixes in `NDArrayOperatorsMixin` using the appraoch described [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin.html).

This works well for numbers, but doesn't work with string dtypes. For example,

```
x = MyNewArrayClass(np.array(["a", "b", "c"]))  
x == "a"
```

raises the following `UFuncTypeError`:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'equal' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> dtype('bool')
```

How can I modify the implementation suggested in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin.html) to support str dtypes?